# Angular side bar to add Tooltip are not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added my angular 7 project side bar to [Tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples) but its not working 
any one know how to add that correctly

Thanks

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
           <!--     <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>-->
                <p><span><img  src="{{menuItem.image}}" width="17" height="17" style="opacity: 0.5;"></span>&nbsp;{{menuItem.tooltip}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {Router, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

    declare const $: any;

    declare interface RouteInfo {
        path: string;
        tooltip: string;
        //icon: string;
        class: string;
        image: string;

       /* isSelected: boolean,
        children: any*/
    }


    export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
        /*{ path: '/dashboard', tooltip: 'Dashboard',  icon: 'home', class: '' },*/
        {
            path: '/projects', tooltip: 'Projects', image: '/assets/img/Projects.svg', class: '',
        },



                {path: '/applications', tooltip: 'Class',  class: '', image: '/assets/img/img1.svg',},
                {path: '/monitoring', tooltip 'Student',  class: '', image: '/assets/img/img2.svg',},
                {path: '/store', tooltip: 'teacher',  class: '', image: '/assets/img/img3.svg',},







        {path: '/profile', title: 'Profile',  class: '', image: '/assets/img/profile.svg',},
            {path: '/billing', title: 'Billing', class: '',image: '/assets/img/Billing.svg',},



];
```

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: When you say, "it's not working"  , do you mean `{{menuItem.tooltip}}` is not getting rendered ? or you don't know how to integrate material tooltip here ? because I can't see ` matTooltip` anywhere in your code

Comment: @ShashankVivek ,   Sir do you have any idea how to  integrate material tooltip, I tried to find some example not found

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same challenge with tool tips in the side bar nav. Did you ever find a solution for this? The answers below didn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo for tooltip integration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-k46f8y?file=index.html)

It can be added as follows:

```
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        matTooltipClass="example-tooltip-red1"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
</button>
```

In your code, you need to add

```
import { MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and do:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ],
```

and in `html` add below attribute

```
 matTooltip="{{menuItem.tooltip}}"
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your solution , Your solution work only html its not work in `sidebar.component.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code in this way to integrate the angular material tooltip to your sidebar.
You can go through [Angular material tooltip documentation for more details](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview).

```
  <ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" 
               [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" 
                matTooltip="{{menuItem.tooltip}}"
                aria-label="{{menuItem.tooltip}}">
                <!--<i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>-->
                <p><span><img  src="{{menuItem.image}}" width="17" height="17" style="opacity: 0.5;"></span></p>
            </a>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I addded but i got console error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'matTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("ass="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]"  [ERROR ->]matTooltip="{{menuItem.tooltip}}"
               aria-label="{{menuItem.tooltip}}">
           <!--"): `

Comment: @core114 You have to import material tooltip module inside your module. Please go through this link https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api

Comment: @core114 is it imported and the same module in which you are using it  ??

Comment: No, I imported to `app.module.ts` and I used this `import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';`

Comment: Can you share your app.module.ts file ??

Comment: I saw your module.ts file, i found that your sidebarComponent is not declared in it. You have to import tooltipModule in the same module in which your SidebarComponent is declared

Comment: no no, `app.moduel.ts` is too long I removed and short it , its can't to put here

Answer (score 0):

sidebar.component.html

add **matTooltip={{menuItem.tooltip}}** in anchor tag

```
 <ul class="nav">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" 
class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" 
                 matTooltip=>
                    <p><span><img  src="{{menuItem.image}}" width="17" height="17" style="opacity: 0.5;"></span></p>
                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I addded but i got console error Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'matTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("ass="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" [ERROR ->]matTooltip="{{menuItem.tooltip}}" aria-label="{{menuItem.tooltip}}"> <!--"):

Comment: can u please add your repo on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slkisd

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `matTooltip` attribute, it'll resolve your issue.

matTooltip - **Tooltip message**

matTooltipPosition - **Tooltip Position**

matTooltipShowDelay - **Tooltip Delay**

Reference Link: https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-tem">
         <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" matTooltip="Tooltip Message here" matTooltipPosition="above" [matTooltipShowDelay]="500">
             <p><span><img  src="{{menuItem.image}}" width="17" height="17" style="opacity: 0.5;"></span></p>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your solution, your solution is not worked for me, I need to add that tooltip in side bar menu look my code